# Azure Application Insights logs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, streaming, azure-application-insights, continuous-delivery

My requirement is to make data transformations with the logs present in Application Insights and then send this transformed data to SQL database tables ? Continuous export is supported only for classic version of App Insights. Can anyone throw some light on how to deal with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends the workspace-based Application Insights with diagnostic settings as the alternative of continuous exports. This approach is a bit expensive.

They have given few alternatives like:

- At the top of a metrics, there is an export button which transfer charts & tables
- Via PowerShell, you can use continuous export feature.
- To access programmatically, Data access REST API available.

You have to set up the diagnostic settings menu as log audit data in Archive to a storage account using JSON Format and then fetch the data to SQL Database table from the storage account.

Refer to the [Stefano Demiliani blog article of exporting app insights through Diagnostic settings](https://demiliani.com/2021/05/27/exporting-application-insights-logs-with-continuous-export-or-diagnostic-settings/) and the Microsoft Official [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry) for more information.